# How do I create request and redirect to the created request?

Tags: c#, nginx, .net-core

I need to redirect the user to `someurl` once logged in, but before that, I need to add a few headers. I tried with named HTTP client but I don't think that's the right path, to begin with. I'm planning to host it on Nginx, is it possible to add headers via Nginx to all traffic from this app? or any other way to achieve this?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // Login Logic

                var someurl = "https://goodurl.com"

                return Redirect(someurl);
            
                ModelState.AddModelError("", @"Your username or password is incorrect. Please try again.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: The server should have default headers/properties when client are missing the properties.  Then you do not need to add anything.

Comment: @jdweng these are basically custom headers and I'm generating the values in this controller, so the server will not have those values.

Comment: Why not make it part of the query.  Usually the unique properties are add to end of url by adding a question mark and then property name and value.

Comment: @jdweng the problem is the url I want to redirect to is not our product and it expects those parameters in request headers.

Comment: Can you fix the client code?  Otherwise you will need your own URL to capture login and create new request to the server.

Comment: Unfortunately node it's a vendors product and parameters have to be passed through headers, can Nginx help in this case, like add those headers to Nginx level?